# ¿Cómo consumir de manera correcta un API Rest desde un cliente por medio del controlador en C# .Net 5?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvc, buenas-prácticas, .net-5

Un saludo a todos y espero puedan ayudarme con una duda.
Actualmente me encuentro desarrollando un proyecto para la empresa que trabajo, pero me ha surgido una duda hasta cierto punto y es sobre el consumo correcto de un **API REST** desde una aplicación web (cliente) de tipo **MVC**.

Actualmente lo consumo con el **HttpClient** y todo va de maravilla, sin embargo, tengo la duda de saber si es correcto que el controlador como tal realice este llamado de manera directa o debería de crear una clase (service) que me provea de toda esta lógica, y así, en el controlador solo llamar al método del service y obtener la respuesta obtenida del API.

Cabe mencionar que mi API se encuentra en una solución independiente del proyecto MVC que funge como mi cliente, ya que esto lo realice de esta manera para cumplir con uno de los puntos que un API necesita, consumirse desde cualquier tipo de aplicación (escritorio, web, móvil).

Este es mi controlador actual que tengo:

```
public class ChecklistController : Controller
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public ChecklistController()
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> ObtenerInformacionUsuarioEquipo(string cValorBuscar)
    {
        var equipo = await ObtenerInformacionEquipo(cValorBuscar);
        var usuario = await ObtenerInformacionUsuario(equipo.cNumeroNomina);

        UsuarioEquipoDTO usuarioEquipoDTO = new UsuarioEquipoDTO
        {
            entEquipo = equipo,
            entUsuario = usuario
        };
        //var dto = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsuarioEquipoDTO>(usuarioEquipoDTO);

        return new JsonResult(usuarioEquipoDTO);
    }

    public async Task<Equipo> ObtenerInformacionEquipo(string cValorBuscar)
    {
        //Se invoca el llamado al api del service giirac
        string apiUrlObtenerInformacionEquipo = $"https://localhost:44324/api/ObtenerInformacionEquipo?cValorBuscar={cValorBuscar}";

        using (_client)
        {
            _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrlObtenerInformacionEquipo);
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage responseEquipo = await _client.GetAsync(apiUrlObtenerInformacionEquipo);

            if (responseEquipo.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var entEquipo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Equipo>(await responseEquipo.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                if (entEquipo != null)
                {
                    return entEquipo;
                }
            }
        }
        
        throw new Exception("Error al obtener la información del equipo");
    }

    public async Task<Usuario> ObtenerInformacionUsuario(string cNumeroNomina)
    {
        string apiUrlObtenerInformacionUsuario = $"https://localhost:44324/api/Checklist/ObtenerInformacionUsuario?cNumeroNomina={cNumeroNomina}";
        //HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

        using (_client)
        {
            _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrlObtenerInformacionUsuario);
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage responseUsuario = await _client.GetAsync(apiUrlObtenerInformacionUsuario);

            if (responseUsuario.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //_client.Dispose();
                var entUsuario = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Usuario>(await responseUsuario.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                ////Se realiza el mapeo global para devolver toda la informacion al JS
                //entUsuarioEquipoDTO = new UsuarioEquipoDTO
                //{
                //    entUsuario = entUsuario,
                //    entEquipo = entEquipo
                //};

                return entUsuario;
            }
        }
        
        
        throw new Exception("Error al obtener la información del equipo");
    }
}
```

Tomando en cuenta que el código es **repetitivo** para cada tipo de solicitud que necesito realizar, la pregunta nuevamente es, ¿Es correcto que el controlador este realizando de manera directa el llamado a la API? ¿Debería de implementar una clase service que me provea de esta lógica? Ejemplo:

```
public async Task<Equipo> ObtenerInformacionEquipo(string cValorBuscar)
    {
        //Se invoca el llamado al api
        var entidad = service.ObtenerInformacionFake(cValorBuscar);

        return entidad;
    }
```

Espero y puedan aclararme esta gran duda amigos, Saludos!

Comment: Ángel, tu pregunta está basada en opiniones y va a terminar cerrada. Dicho esto, **ya respondiste tu pregunta**. En mi **opinión** una buena practica es que tu código sea DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), y sus componentes sean SOLID, sobre todo la S de Single Responsibility. El controlador no es responsable de todas esas llamadas. Todo eso debe ser delegado a un servicio.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, lo tomare en cuenta.

Comment: Me parece que esta pregunta está sujeta a la opinión de cada cual, pero bueno, te daré la mía. Yo definitivamente implementaría una capa de servicio que proporcione los datos. Mañana cambia la forma en que obtienes los datos (obteniendo la info de un json o de una base de datos) y tienes que refactorizar completamente toda tu aplicación porque todo está mezclado. Ahora mismo la app es pequeña, no se nota, pero cuando una app crece es incluso recomendable 3 capas. Una capa de acceso a datos, una de lógica de negocio y finalmente tus controladores.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario!